# Provider hosted app query string passing works in SharePoint 2013 but not in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2019

Our customer has an on-premise SharePoint 2013 environment with a provider hosted app that uses query strings as parameters. The environment is accessible only in the intranet.

```
https://sp2013.example.local/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?instance_id={<GUID>}&myParam=new
```

This works, i.e. the app can read the value of the parameter `myParam`.

This same app has been ported into a SharePoint 2019 environment, where it works when called without any parameters. However when called with a parameter, the parameter is ignored and the app behaves as if it were called without any.

```
https://sp2019.example.local/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?instance_id={<another GUID>}&myParam=new
```

Pointers to solution appreciated.

Comment: Additional info: the passing works with MS IE on SP2013 but not with Google Chrome. It works neither with Chrome nor MS Edge on SP2019 (the organisation does not use MS IE when accessing the new environment.